# Удалить часть строки

Tags: php

Наверное глупый вопрос, но не знаю как это сделать..
Имеем строку типа:

```
<div class="phone" data-number="+7 (111) 11-11-11">+7 (111) 11-11-11</div>
```

Нужно удалить весь тег, оставив только номер. Номер может быть любым. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!)